# Containable behavior does not return from depth 3 - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, recursion, cakephp-1.2, belongs-to, containable

I use CakePHP 1.2.6 and have the following relations:

Showcase HABTM User belongsTo Galleryitem hasOne Image

I try to get all the data related to a Showcase, and therefor also all its users with their Galleryitem -> Image. I use the following query:

```
$showcase = $this->Showcase->find('first',
    array('conditions'=>array('Showcase.id'=>$id),
        'contain'=> array(
            'User' => array(
                'Galleryitem' => array(
                    'Image'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This does returns and empty array of `Galleryitem` and thus no `Image` records at all.
If I try the following:

```
$showcase = $this->Showcase->User->find('first',
    array(
        'contain'=> array(
            'Galleryitem' => array(
                'Image'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I do get some data here about `Image`. So it seems the depth plays a role here.

Other factors that came to mind were the `belongsTo` relation between `User` and `Galleryitem`.

What causes my query not to return data from a depth of 3?

**Update**
The set of Showcase relations is in my project much more branched than I explain above. All the other branches properply show up. So I guess it has to do with specific relations in this branch, the `User belongsTo Galleryitem`.

Strange still, because the other branches contain this very same set of `Galleryitem hasOne Image` relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually go for the dot syntax (which I can't see in the book):

```
$this->Showcase->contain('User','User.GalleryItem','User.GalleryItem.Image');
$showcase = $this->Showcase->User->find('first');
```

although I'm struggling to find a three-deep example in any of my code.

Comment: This (albeit deprecated) post by Felix Geisendörfer dates back to the early days of containable and might help to explain: http://debuggable.com/posts/bringing-the-cold-war-to-cakephp-12-the-containable-behavior:480f4dd6-2b50-4d7b-ab05-418dcbdd56cb

Comment: +1, A.B.C is the only thing that works for me too for deeper relations.

Comment: Thanks! It seems my problem did reside in secondary code. After rewriting/cleaning up it worked.
By the way: I found that a `fields` array in one branch about e.g. `Image` affects the other branches that contain an `Image` field. The last `fields` array dictates the others.